# What's a good grammatical antonym for the auxiliary verb 始める?

Tags: auxiliaries, antonyms

What's a good grammatical opposite for the auxiliary usage of the verb 始める, meaning that you're describing the beginning of a verb?

Comment: Are you talking about 〜終わる・終える?  Otherwise I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antonym of *to begin* is *to end*. As a matter of fact the antonym of 始める is 終{お}わる. It does work the same way as 始める.

Example:

> 本を読み始める (start reading a book) -- 本を読み終わる (finish reading a book)

Note: You can also use 終{お}える in place of 終わる.

Comment: Cool, thx! Gonna accept when SE let's me. ;)